# Dynamoose TypeScript ValidationException: The number of conditions on the keys is invalid when using .get()

Tags: dynamoose

Given the below dynamodb schema for creating the table:

```
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "id",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "name",
      "KeyType": "RANGE"
    }
  ],
```

and dynamoose schema in code:

```
new dynamoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
```

Was seeing `ValidationException: The number of conditions on the keys is invalid` error when using `repository.get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution: Need to specify the range key in dynamoose schema.

```
  id: {
    type: String,
    hashKey: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    rangeKey: true,
  },
```